# I need to removeClass when hitting the back button on a browser once it reaches the homepage

Tags: javascript

I have [hasher.js](https://github.com/millermedeiros/Hasher) on my site, I don't fully understand it, but here's any reference used in my javascript file.

```
function activateKeyNav()
    {
        // Description: register keypress event on document object
        jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
            switch(event.which)
            {
                case 27: // escape
                    hasher.setHash();
                    $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');
                    $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
                    $('#backtoprojects').addClass('is-hidden');
                    $('#project-close').addClass('is-hidden');
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
function goToNextProject()
    {
        if(projects[currentProject].rght)
            updateHash(projects[currentProject].rght);
    }

    function goToPrevProject()
    {
        if(projects[currentProject].lft)
             updateHash(projects[currentProject].lft);
    }
function updateHash(project)
    {
        hasher.setHash(project);
    }
$('#backtoprojects a').on('click', function(){
        hasher.setHash();
        $('#backtoprojects').addClass('is-hidden');
        deactivateKeyNav();
    });
$('#project-close').on('click', function(){
        hasher.setHash();
        $('#project-close').addClass('is-hidden');
    });
$('[data-type="projectLoader"]').click(function() {

        var proj = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-project');
        // loadProject(proj)
        $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');

        updateHash(proj);
        return false;
        // return loadProject(proj);

    });

crossroads.addRoute('/{project}', function(project) {
        console.log(project);
        loadProject(project);
        currentProject = project;
        deactivateKeyNav();
        activateKeyNav();

    });

    crossroads.addRoute('/', function() {
        $('#backtoprojects').click();
    });
    crossroads.routed.add(console.log, console);

    function parseHash(newHash, oldHash) {
    crossroads.parse(newHash);
    };

    hasher.initialized.add(parseHash); //parse initial hash
    hasher.changed.add(parseHash); //parse hash changes
    hasher.init(); //start listening for history change
```

I don't think any html is necessary since it has to do with the browser and backspace.

When I'm in a project it adds the /#/project-name to the url. When I hit backspace or in the browser press back it takes away "project-name" but you still remain in the project. It should load the homepage back.

Is it possible to do a `document ready`? Or a `removeClass`? If I could do `$('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');` this would kill the project and bring you back to the homepage.

Here's a live [example](http://darrenbachan.com/).

**UPDATE #1**
This worked for the backspace key. How could I combine to make case 27 and case 8 to do the same thing without having to dupe the code? `code 27 && code 8`? I still need a solution for the back button in browser.

```
case 8: // backspace
    $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');
    $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
    $('#backtoprojects').addClass('is-hidden');
    $('#project-close').addClass('is-hidden');
    break;
```

**UPDATE #2**

```
window.history.back();
window.history.go(-1);
```

These couldn't work, I realize now. I could be 4 projects deep into the history. I don't know how to target this.

Comment: The ESC key does exactly that. Perhaps its code can be used for the same effect?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen yeah, the removeClass does this, but if it's possible to map it to the keyboard backspace, can the same be done for the browser's back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messing around with the js I got this to work. I don't need to target the backspace button either.

```
crossroads.addRoute('/', function() {
        $('#backtoprojects').click();
        $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');
        $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
        $('#backtoprojects').addClass('is-hidden');
        $('#project-close').addClass('is-hidden');
    });
```